# Newbee angular right out of the box

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm, angular-cli

So I download and install Visual Studio Community

---

### vs v 16.4.0

I create a new project using the

- File
- New Project
- ASP.NET Core Web Application
- Create a new ASP.NET Core web application
- Angular A project template for creating an ASP.NET Core application with Angular

---

### Then when I run it I get:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
>
> ```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "51676"`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> ```
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> ))
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> ```
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "51676"`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> ```
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>   Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "51676"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: ))
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.get_Result()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout(Task task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>
> Show raw exception details 
>   InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "51676"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the vecwebportaql@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>
> Show raw exception details

Could I have some help please with this out-of-the-box example?

Answer (score 0):

you have:
"The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests"

And:
"'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I dont think you set it up properly.

Try here:
https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/creating-angular-projects-with-angular-cli-e32b2cb486da

Answer (score 0):

From that I got the Powershell line:

npm install -g @angular/cli

After a rebuild,  I get a new error:

==========================

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.

=======================

it is the code:

=====
startup.cs

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
// To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
// see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
     **spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")**
     });
};
```

======

That fails on the spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")

So I assume the Angular CLIent Server is not working.  Please advise.